# Add blur view in MKOverlay on map in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, blur

I am trying to add a blur to an MKMapView. That is, I want to blur some not necessarily rectangular region on the map.

I have tried setting up an MKOverlayRenderer that will draw a blur, but I have been having immense difficulty setting it up such that the blur affects what is underneath instead of just showing a gray area or nothing.

This is my attempt, and I know that it won't work, but I just don't know how to fix it.

```
class BlurOverlayRenderer: MKOverlayRenderer {
    var blurView: UIVisualEffectView?

    override init(overlay: MKOverlay) {
        super.init(overlay: overlay)
        blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
    }

    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        context.draw(blurView?.layer as! CGLayer, at: CGPoint.zero)
    }
}
```

How can I fix this renderer to blur the area beneath it on the map?

Answer (score 0):

`UIVisualEffectView` will not work because it should be in `UIView` hierarchy so UIKit can find underlying views and create a blurred picture.
But `MKMapView` is using custom layer-based rendering tree. That's why you get gray area.

What you can try to do, is to create a picture of the `context` in the corresponding `mapRect` then blur it and draw at the same place.